# Always-on proxy

Tags: ubuntu, proxy

My use case: I am in Ubuntu 16.04. Sometimes I am in an environment where I need to configure a proxy. I need to do this in lots of places: proxy for chrome, for apt, for pip, for docker, for bash, ... Fine, I am happy to configure all those tools **once**.

What I want is to have a local proxy running that I can toggle with a single command. This "forward proxy" will either put the proxy headers to the real proxy, when in the corporate environment, or just pass the traffic transparently, when on the road.

These are the detailed requirements:

1. Running locally on my system (laptop)
2. Always on
3. Can work in proxy or transparent mode
4. Can be easily toggled, with the command line
5. Does NTLM

Currently I am using `cntlm` and it satisfies most of my needs, but it can not be put in transparent mode.

Something I could try is to, with `sed` or similar, tweak the `no_proxy` parameter to include all destinations, and then restart the service. But this seems an ugly hack, and I am not sure it will work.

Is there a better solution? What I had in mind was a kind of service in front of `cntlm` which can proxy to either `cntlm` or transparently pass trafic, depending on configuration.